# What’s the difference between something ends and something comes to an end?

Tags: difference

- let’s go skiing before winter ends.
- let’s go skiing before winter comes to an end.

Is there any difference between the two sentences above? If not, is there any case where the use of both expressions conveys different meanings?

Comment: I would say that the two sentences are essentially the same.  "Comes to an end" is slightly more formal and poetic.

Comment: Perhaps, there might be *just the slightest* bit of difference in connotation -- "comes to an end," *might* imply a *permanent* end... and perhaps not.

Comment: Similar to what stangdon said, "comes to and end" means the same thing, but is more dramatic